# XML facebook feed

Tags: xml, perl, facebook

Can I get an XML feed of my personal facebook news?

Is there any existing Perl CPAN modules for parsing the XML feed?

Answer (score 5):

[WWW::Facebook::API::Feed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Facebook::API::Feed).